How can I set the terminal's default working directory conditionally depending on whether it's opened in a workspace or not?
I'd favor Visual Studio Code to provide the following context-based behavior on opening terminals:

Whilst in a workspace: Open terminal in the workspace root or whatever is defined for multi-root workspaces (default behavior of VSCode)

Whilst outside of a workspace, having a file opened and active: Open terminal at the active file's location, not at the user profile

When there is neither a workspace nor an active file opened, then and only then the terminal should resort to the user profile directory as a fallback


I know that by defining terminal.integrated.cwd": "${fileDirname}" I can achieve 2., however, this also overrides the desired terminal behavior for workspaces as well. Ideally, there would be something along ${workspaceFolder} if ${isWorkspace} else ${fileDirname}.
Is there even any way to achieve both as a global setting or at least an extension that hooks into the mechanic to make it conditional without introducing a separate command?

not that I know of. if you raise a feature-request issue ticket, please add a link here to it.
